# MYSQL Wont start - using Xibo on Xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp, innodb

Restarted my server
getting no where with this error
tried changing port numbers
trid changing permissions on the specific it asked.
any help with this will be greatly appreciated.
I'm using XIBO on xamppp and the MYSQL database wont start so now i cant configure the XIBO, but when XAMPP is running without MYSQL i can view the content.

Below are the logs of the problem i am having.
Again thanking you in advance regarding this.

```
2013-11-27 09:29:11 848 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-11-27 09:29:11 ea0 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2013-11-27 09:29:11 848 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-11-27 09:29:11 848 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-11-27 09:29:11 848 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-11-27 09:29:11 848 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-11-27 09:29:11 848 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2013-11-27 09:29:11 848 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-11-27 09:29:11 848 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-11-27 09:29:11 848 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 3140458 and 3140458 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 3747628 in the ib_logfiles!
2013-11-27 09:29:11 848 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2013-11-27 09:29:11 848 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2013-11-27 09:29:11 848 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2013-11-27 09:29:11 848 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace mysql/innodb_table_stats uses space ID: 1 at filepath: .\mysql\innodb_table_stats.ibd. Cannot open tablespace xibo/bandwidth which uses space ID: 1 at filepath: .\xibo\bandwidth.ibd
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\xibo\bandwidth.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

Answer (score 0):

If your computer running "skype", just quit it then start MySQL. Because they both may use same port number